# What is the tdnf equivalent of 'yum groupinstall'?

Tags: linux

is there an equivalent for this?

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

In the `tdnf` help we only see the following:

```
List of Main Commands

check-local               Checks local rpm folder for problems
check-update              Check for available package upgrades
clean                     Remove cached data
distro-sync               Synchronize installed packages to the latest available versions
download                  download a package
download-nodeps           download a package without dependencies
downgrade                 downgrade a package
erase                     Remove a package or packages from your system
help                      Display a helpful usage message
info                      Display details about a package or group of packages
install                   Install a package or packages on your system
list                      List a package or groups of packages
makecache                 Generate the metadata cache
provides                  Find what package provides the given value
remove                    Remove a package or packages from your system
reinstall                 reinstall a package
repolist                  Display the configured software repositories
repoquery                 Query repositories
reposync                  Download all packages from one or more repositories to a directory
search                    Search package details for the given string
update                    Upgrade a package or packages on your system (same as 'upgrade')
updateinfo                Display advisories about packages
upgrade                   Upgrade a package or packages on your system
upgrade-to                Upgrade a package on your system to the specified version
```

So then .. did that `Development Packages` grouping simply disappear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use command like:

```
dnf group install "Development Tools"
```

or

```
dnf install @"Development Tools"
```